# Installing & configuring JBoss WildFly in CentOS 8 with different user

Tags: linux, jboss, wildfly, centos8, appserver

I want to install and configure `JBoss WildFly 26.0.0.Final` as a `systemd/init.d` service in my Linux VM (CentOS 8) with different user - not with the default `wildfly` user.

I have gone through the steps in many of the How-To-Dos and also on the official site. But would like to know what changes regarding the user, I need to make for such configuration.

Some of the links I have gone through do not specify the changes to be made.
[Installing on CentOS 7](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wildfly-on-centos-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Please look in the etc directory for the wildfly folder. there is a `wildfly.conf` there, according to your specifications, further information is required

1. **Location of JDK -:** `JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/oracle/jdk-17`
2. **Location of WildFly -:** `JBOSS_HOME=/opt/wildfly`
3. **The username who should own the process -:** `JBOSS_USER=wildfly`
4. **The configuration you want to run -:** `WILDFLY_CONFIG=standalone.xml`
5. **The mode you want to run -:** `WILDFLY_MODE=standalone`

I faced the same problem as you. Only after I added the relevant information does everything run smoothly